# How enable content-length header using .htaccess?

Tags: apache-httpd, download, file-transfer, header-file, htaccess

I have a seriously big problem, when i download any file for example: myfile.zip, or when i load a page for example: myserver.com/welcome.html, the response headers not include content-length and the samething when i download a file, the download show this:

[image: not show file size]

I other words, does not show the size of the file and not show the progress downloaded, because my website not answer content-length, on any file.

The same problem with a normal page, response header below:

[image]

[image]

My .htaccess code:

```
Header set Content-Length %{HTTP:Content-Length}
ErrorDocument 404 /error/NotFound(.html)
ErrorDocument 403 /error/Forbidden(.html)
```

Comment: I am confused by the combination of nginx and `.htaccess` here - which are you using at the point the header would be generated?

Comment: Really so sorry, i write wrong my server, my server is Apache/2.4.25, edition of the question already made.

Comment: 1) The question has not been edited. 2) You have a *screenshot* showing nginx.

Comment: Im confussed too, my response header are nginx but the directory listing say: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at myserver.com/files  Port 80

Comment: really so strange

Comment: Already updated you can see it.

Comment: Also i add the hosting provider: https://www.hostpapa.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The really problem are that you are using a Low quality hosting, that uses Behold Thumper http server, it server mixes the power of apache and nginx, is good for build php websites, but is bad for serve files, i build a solution based on F#, when you call "Header set" you are breaking the directory listing, look below the solution >>

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [NS,E=no-gzip:1,E=dont-vary:1]
SetEnv no-gzip 1 #Allow content-length
Options @F MultiViews #Fsharp provider enable
deny access Nginx $0 #Block nginx
ServeOnly Apache $1 #Allow default apache
```

Please ask right the next time, asks with much editions can be low quality questions.

If you want personal suggest come to my github: geeekyeGirl

Comment: Thank you so much, finally an answer that really helps, i already test your code, works fine, but anyways i'm thinking on change of hosting provider, which do you recommend me?

Comment: I highly recommend https://www.namecheap.com/, is powerfull, stable and thinked on professional developers, in general the low quality hosting are focused to bloggers. I hav bad experiences about hostpapa, hostinger, godaddy and vitrexprivate.

Comment: One question more, why your code works only in hostpapa, i already open an account in namecheap just now and returns internal server error?

Comment: The configuration that i built is for hostpapa, hostpapa have different .htaccess version compared namecheap, namecheap uses ht4v that is the new replacement of the old ht module, it combines F# code, the older versions will no support it.

Comment: Thank you, so much :)

Comment: In resume namecheap does not need it code...

Comment: thank you again, lets talk on github :)